# How to count incoming messages from a "stream" in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, stream, thread-synchronization

So I'm receiving numerous messages from a stream - well, it's not a stream per se, it's really a method that's fired off when a message is received - and I would like to count the number of messages received in 10 seconds.

Here's what I have so far:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.net.URI;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

public class ExampleClient extends WebSocketClient {

    private float messagesRecievedCount;

    public ExampleClient(URI serverUri) {
        super(serverUri);
        System.out.println("Created object");
        setMessagesRecievedCount(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
        System.out.println("Connection established!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s) {
        setMessagesRecievedCount(getMessagesRecievedCount() + 1);
    }

    public void getMessagesPerMinute(){
        float start = getMessagesRecievedCount();
        float end = 0;
        long ten = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < ten) {
            end = getMessagesRecievedCount();
        }
        System.out.println("start: "+start+" end: "+end+
                "Total messages: "+ (end-start)+"\n");
    }

    public float getMessagesRecievedCount() {
        return messagesRecievedCount;
    }

    public void setMessagesRecievedCount(float messagesRecievedCount) {
        this.messagesRecievedCount = messagesRecievedCount;
    }
}
```

I have a global variable `messagesRecievedCount` which keeps a running count of messages received from a websocket stream. Whenever a message is received the `onMessage()` method is fired and it updates the message count. I want to count the number of messages received in 10 seconds (and extrapolate it to a minute) - for which I have the `getMessagesPerMinute()`.

Obviously the way I'm doing it is not smart - it's blocking and the count of messages after 10 seconds is the same (when actually it isn't, I've actually received 20 messages). I feel like I should be doing threads but I don't know how to go about it. What would you suggest? I'm really new to this and just tinkering around.

This is the main class where I'm calling `ExampleClient.java` from:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication  {

    private WebSocketSession clientSession;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public DemoApplication () throws URISyntaxException {
        ExampleClient c = new ExampleClient( new URI( "wss://example.com/" ) );
        c.connect();
        c.getMessagesPerMinute();
    }
    
}
```

The `c.connect()` establishes the connection and the `onMessage()` is triggered soon after!

Comment: [Dropwizard metrics](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.1.2/) and [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io) are two libraries that are great for collecting and reporting these kind of metrics.

Comment: @dnault Dropwizard metrics is a really cool library! That solved the purpose! However I would be interested to see how I can do this the traditional way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actully runs fo 1 second (1000ms, I don't know if this is a typo or a voluntary simplification). One other problem is that it calls `end = getMessagesRecievedCount();` repeatedly inside a while loop, while you actually need only the starting and final value. A way to solve this would be using `Thread.sleep()` (if you never need to cancel the counting midway):

```
    public void getMessagesPerMinute(){
    float start = getMessagesRecievedCount();
    float end = 0;
    try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("do something");
    }
    end = getMessagesRecievedCount();
    System.out.println("start: "+start+" end: "+end+
            "Total messages: "+ (end-start)+"\n");
    }
```

For blocking the important thing is that this code runs in a different thread that the one updating the value of `messagesRecievedCount` or doing other things that you may want to do in the meanwhile, so calling it inside a new thread is probably the best solution. I'm not familiar with the framework you are using so it may be already using different threads that better suit this purpose.

If you intend to do something more with the variable `messagesRecievedCount` some synchronization would be required, but for an estimate of the number of messages for minute this should be good enough.

Here is some test code I used that you can hopefully adapt to better suit your case and play with to pinpoint the problem. The difference is quite constant in this case, but the values are clearly updated. Making the ExampleClient instance public is a shortcut which should probaby be avoided in the actual code.

```
public class Test{

    public static ExampleClient example=new ExampleClient();
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread a=new MessagesPerTenSecondFetcher();
        Thread b=new MessagesPerTenSecondFetcher();
        Thread c=new MessagesPerTenSecondFetcher();
        Thread d= new MessageProducer();
        a.start();
        d.start();
        b.start();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("do something");
        }
        c.start();
    }
}

class ExampleClient {
    private float messagesRecievedCount;

    public void onMessage(String s) {
        setMessagesRecievedCount(getMessagesRecievedCount() + 1);
    }

    public void getMessagesPerMinute(){
        float start = getMessagesRecievedCount();
        float end = 0;
        try{
                Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("do something");
        }
        end = getMessagesRecievedCount();
        System.out.println("start: "+start+" end: "+end+
                "Total messages: "+ (end-start)+"\n");
    }

    public float getMessagesRecievedCount() {
        return messagesRecievedCount;
    }

    public void setMessagesRecievedCount(float messagesRecievedCount) {
        this.messagesRecievedCount = messagesRecievedCount;
    }
}

class MessagesPerTenSecondFetcher extends Thread{
     @Override
     public void run(){
         Test.example.getMessagesPerMinute();
     }
}

class MessageProducer extends Thread{
     @Override
     public void run(){
        for(int i =0; i<100;i++){
            Test.example.onMessage("a");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(130);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("do something");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I looked up DropWizard library in Java for metrics reporting - would you recommend using that or is my current implementation (with your modifications) enough?

Comment: You should get different values in different threads. If multiple threads modify `messagesRecievedCount` simultaneously you can get some unespected behaviour if you don't handle it properly, but if you are just reading the value it should be safe. I'm quite new to multithreading and some good reading before dealing with it is advisable. A library would have some common problems already solved for you or may overcomplicate your project, I don't know DropWizard.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just tried this out and it doesn't look like I receive updated values for `messagesReceived` -- Do you think it may be due to how I call this method?

Comment: It could be. Or you could be using new intances of ExempleClient or calling the different threads at the same time or what not. Writing a simplified example would help you understand what's going on, pinpoint the problem or at least will lead to a good new question.

Comment: I updated the description to include how I'm calling this function :)